# Nested sortable functionality using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, razor-pages

I want to add the sortable functionality only to the charts.

> Index.cshmtml

```
   <div id="sortable" class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 padding hidden" id=@($"chartNumber{Model.Charts[0].ChartOrder}")>
            <figure class="figure">
                <div id=@($"container{Model.Charts[0].ChartOrder}")></div>
            </figure>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12 hidden" id="@($"chartNumber{Model.Charts[1].ChartOrder}")">
            <div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 Grid pull-left padding">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div style="border: 2px solid blue; height: 100px" class="col-lg-12">Tool box 1</div>
                        <div style="border: 2px solid blue; height: 100px" class="col-lg-12">Tool box 2</div>
                        <div style="border: 2px solid blue; height: 100px" class="col-lg-12">Tool box 3</div>
                        <div style="border: 2px solid blue; height: 100px" class="col-lg-12">Tool box 4</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 pull-right padding">
                    <figure class="figure">
                        <div id=@($"container{Model.Charts[1].ChartOrder}")></div>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

> Javascript.js

```
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        items: '> div > div > div:not(.Grid)',
        containment: 'parent',
        cursor: 'move',
        scroll: false,
        update: function () {
            var data = $("#sortable").sortable('toArray');
        }
    });
```

> Output
> [image]

When i drag the pie chart the the tool box which is on left side is also dragging, i want that only pie chart should be dragable, and when i put the pie chart on the top then the chart which is on the  top will be automatically placed on the place of pie chart. And please height of the charts will not be changes

Comment: Would suggest adding handles to help the User know what can be sorted. You may want to use `items` to specify the specific items that should be sorted. This way you can nest sortables and not sort too little or too much.

Comment: Yes  @Twisty i used items to specify the specific items that should be sorted, but the issue is when i try to the the cnage orders of the charts then height of the Grid get worse, can you please give me a sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) function of the of the jquery

```
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
```